# Given an applications package name, how to know if that application supports widgets on homescreen

Tags: android, widget

Given an applications package name how to know if that application supports widgets on homescreen ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Wasser's solution was my first guess too, but it failed to detect one of my widget. 
Here's another approach if the first one doesn't work for you.

You can list all receivers for the ACTION_APP_WIDGET_UPDATE action, which allhome screen widget should listen to, and then filter by package name :

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
        Log.i("package", info.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PackageManager and call `getPackageInfo(packageName, GET_RECEIVERS)` for the application.

Loop through all `PackageInfo.receivers` and call `PackageManager.getReceiverInfo(componentName, GET_META_DATA)` for each `ActivityInfo` object in `PackageInfo.receivers`.

Look at the field `metadata`. This may be null or it may contain a Bundle. If it contains a Bundle, look in the Bundle for an item with key `"android.appwidget.provider"`. If you find that then you can be pretty sure that the application supports widgets on the homescreen.